# Compare two objects by calculating a Min-Hash

Tags: hash, typescript, dimensionality-reduction

I need to compare different states of Java/Type-script objects. These objects change during execution, so I can't compare them directly. I need to compare them according to an calculated 'hash value' which I'm able to store.

Typically, the [Min-Hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinHash) algorithm works great for this kind of problem. However, Min-Hash is based purely on comparing sets of strings, and hence can't compare sets whose content is somehow 'ordered', i.e. numeric.

Let me explain what I mean. Consider an object made up of

```
 "FirstValue"
 "SecondValue"
 "42"
```

which gets hashed to `100101010`. At a different time the same object consist of

```
 "FirstValue"
 "SecondValue"
 "41"
```

which results in the hash `100010010`

Now typically these hashes are compared by checking the Hamming distance.

```
 100101010 XOR
 100010010 
 =========
 000111000 --> Hamming Distance = 3
```

which allows to calculate their similarity according to the [Jaccard index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) as  `(9-3)/9=0.66`.

However, I would like to see the minor change from `42` to `41` somehow reflected in the hash. I.e, the similarity between both states should be more like `0.95`. The exact number doesn't matter.

How would I do that, without the requirement to store a lot of additional values?

Comment: I guess you should compare original strings after you compared the hashes?

Comment: The problem is, to compare the `41` with `42` I need to store the number `42` along the hash. Only this way I can compare the old state (the `42`) with the new state (the `41`) --> more ram usage.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to use random bit flips.

Regular strings get hashed by Min-Hash. The resulting hash is altered by random bit flips. The probability of a bit flip at each position of the hash is proportional to the integer to compare.

```
"FirstValue"
"SecondValue"
"42"
```

gets hashed by first hashing `"FirstValue"` and `"SecondValue"` which results in `100101011`.

The `42` now gets incorporated into the hash the following way:

- As I'm expecting values between `20` and `50` the `42` is at `73.3%` of that range.
- The probability of a bit flip at each position is then `0.733*weight`

However, I still need to fiddle with the random number generators' seed to make the hash deterministic.